# KL divergence in R using base 2 logarithm

Tags: r

I want to find JS divergence of two distributions in R. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) says that Jensen–Shannon divergence is bounded by 1, given that one uses the base 2 logarithm. I want that my resulting JS divergence lies between 0 and 1. I am using KLdiv function in R to find JS:

> ```
> JSD(P || Q)= 1/2*D(P || M) + 1/2*D(Q || M)
> ```
>
> where Kullback–Leibler divergence KLdiv(P,M) = D(P || M)

But I want to specify that I need base 2 logarithm. Looks like KLdiv does not allow me to specify which log I want to use. Any clue as to how to do that?

Ok this is the R code for finding JSdivergence between 2 distributions     ..

```
library(flexmix)
m <- 0.5 *(dist1 + dist2) #JSD(P||Q)=0.5*D(P||M) + 0.5*D(Q||M), where M=0.5*(P+Q)
Dpm <- KLdiv(cbind(dist1,m))
Dqm <- KLdiv(cbind(m,dist2))
js <- 0.5*Dpm + 0.5*Dqm
```

I want a JS value between 0 and 1 which as per [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) is possible only if I take base 2 logarithm. How can I do this with my exisiting R code

Comment: If you do not add more R content to this, you should ask the moderator to move it tos stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok this is the R code for finding JSdivergence between 2 distributions     ..
y <- cbind(dist1,dist2) 
y2 <- cbind(dist2,dist1)
kl <- KLdiv(y)
js <- 0.5*KLdiv(y) + 0.5*KLdiv(y2)
I want a JS value between 0 and 1 which as per wiki is possible only if I take base 2 logarithm. How can I do this with my exisiting R code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, it holds that

[image]

meaning that if you want to compute the logarithm of b to base a but you only have a function that computes the logarithm of any number to base x, you can still easily get the logarithm of that number to base a.

Hence:

[image]

So if you want to determine the KL divergence with respect to base x, you just have to divide the result of computing the KL divergence with base `e` by the logarithm of x to base  `e` (or whatever base the implementation of KLdiv is using).

BTW, you forgot to mention which KLdiv function you are using.

Secondly, by looking at your R code I think you might want to re-read on JS divergence, in particular the definition of M.

Comment: +1 for the great formulas. I've envied the stats.stackexchange site for its superior abilities in this respect but you seem to have figure out how to get SO to do the same. (and extra credit for reinforcing the need to post the name of packages being used for stange functions.) Oh, damnation. You posted images.

Comment: Thanks @fotNelton. I have used the KLdiv function from the flexmix package. And thanks for correcting my JS divergence calculation. I missed on the M part and have corrected it now.

Comment: @DWin: lol, I feel exactly the same. Having the ability to enter formulas and having them rendered automatically should be the de facto standard.

Comment: @tan: You're very welcome. If the above does work for you, I'd appreciate it if you'd accept the answer :)